# Usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Is $\mathscr{B}_{o}={{B(x,\frac{1}{n}) : x \in \mathbb{Q}, n \in \mathbb{N}}}$ a basis for usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$? Justify.

It is sure that if $x$ is a rational number then we can always find such $B$, but in the case of irrational number $y \in \mathbb{R}$ whether can I find such an rational x and a natural number which satisfies the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take any open set $U$ and element $y\in U$. Since $U$ is open there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that $B(y,\varepsilon)\subseteq U$. Pick $n$ with $\frac1n<\frac\varepsilon3$ and pick a rational number $x\in B(y,\frac1n)$. Note that $y\in B(x,\frac1n)\subseteq U$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's true.

If we have some irrational $y$ which is contained in some interval $(a,b)$, then take $n$ so small that $r = \frac{1}{n}$ is smaller than both $y-a > 0$ and $b-y > 0$. This ensures that $B(y,r) \subseteq (a,b)$.

Then find some rational $x$ in $(y-r,y+r)$. Then show that $B(x, \frac{1}{2n})$ is a set in $\mathcal{B}_0$ that sits inside $(a,b)$.